# OpenCV calibrateCamera - assertion failed (nimages > 0 && nimages == (int)imagePoints1.total()

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, camera-calibration

The complete error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (nimages > 0 && nimages == 
(int)imagePoints1.total() && (!imgPtMat2 || nimages == 
(int)imagePoints2.total())) in collectCalibrationData, file C:\OpenCV
\sources\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp, line 3164
```

The code:

```
cv::VideoCapture kalibrowanyPlik;   //the video

cv::Mat frame;
cv::Mat testTwo; //undistorted
cv::Mat cameraMatrix = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 2673.579, 0, 1310.689, 0, 2673.579, 914.941, 0, 0, 1);
cv::Mat distortMat = (cv::Mat_<double>(1, 4) << -0.208143,  0.235290,  0.001005,  0.001339);
cv::Mat intrinsicMatrix = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
cv::Mat distortCoeffs = cv::Mat::zeros(8, 1, CV_64F);
//there are two sets for testing purposes. Values for the first two came from GML camera calibration app. 

std::vector<cv::Mat> rvecs;
std::vector<cv::Mat> tvecs;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f> > imagePoints;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f> > objectPoints;

kalibrowanyPlik.open("625.avi");
    //cv::namedWindow("Distorted", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //gotta see things
    //cv::namedWindow("Undistorted", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

int maxFrames = kalibrowanyPlik.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);    
int success = 0;    //so we can do the calibration only after we've got a bunch

for(int i=0; i<maxFrames-1; i++) {    
    kalibrowanyPlik.read(frame);
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners; //creating these here so they're effectively reset each time
    std::vector<cv::Point3f> objectCorners;

    int sizeX = kalibrowanyPlik.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //imageSize
    int sizeY = kalibrowanyPlik.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

    cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY); //must be gray

    cv::Size patternsize(9,6); //interior number of corners

    bool patternfound = cv::findChessboardCorners(frame, patternsize, corners, cv::CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv::CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv::CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK); //finding them corners

    if(patternfound == false) { //gotta know 
        qDebug() << "failure";
    }
    if(patternfound) {
        qDebug() << "success!";
            std::vector<cv::Point3f> objectCorners; //low priority issue - if I don't do this here, it becomes empty. Not sure why. 
            for(int y=0; y<6; ++y) {
                for(int x=0; x<9; ++x) { 
                    objectCorners.push_back(cv::Point3f(x*28,y*28,0)); //filling the array
                }
            }

            cv::cornerSubPix(frame, corners, cv::Size(11, 11), cv::Size(-1, -1),
            cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));

            cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_GRAY2BGR); //I don't want gray lines

            imagePoints.push_back(corners); //filling array of arrays with pixel coord array
            objectPoints.push_back(objectCorners); //filling array of arrays with real life coord array, or rather copies of the same thing over and over
            cout << corners << endl << objectCorners;
            cout << endl << objectCorners.size() << "___" << objectPoints.size() <<  "___" << corners.size() <<  "___" << imagePoints.size() << endl;
            cv::drawChessboardCorners(frame, patternsize, cv::Mat(corners), patternfound); //drawing. 

            if(success > 5) {
                double rms =  cv::calibrateCamera(objectPoints, corners, cv::Size(sizeX, sizeY), intrinsicMatrix, distortCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, cv::CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS); 
//error - caused by passing CORNERS instead of IMAGEPOINTS. Also, imageSize is 640x480, and I've set the central point to 1310... etc
                cout << endl << intrinsicMatrix << endl << distortCoeffs << endl;
                cout << "\nrms - " << rms << endl;
            }
            success = success + 1;

        //cv::imshow("Distorted", frame);
        //cv::imshow("Undistorted", testTwo);
        }
    }
```

I've done a little bit of reading [(This was an especially informative read)](https://adventuresandwhathaveyou.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/opencv-error-messages-suck/), including over a dozen threads made here on StackOverflow, and all I found is that this error is produced by either by uneven imagePoints and objectPoints or by them being partially null or empty or zero (and links to tutorials that don't help). None of that is the case - the output from .size() check is:

```
54___7___54___7
```

For objectCorners (real life coords), objectPoints (number of arrays inserted) and the same for corners (pixel coords) and imagePoints. They're not empty either, the output is:

```
(...)
277.6792, 208.92903;
241.83429, 208.93048;
206.99866, 208.84637;
(...)
84, 56, 0;
112, 56, 0;
140, 56, 0;
168, 56, 0;
(...)
```

A sample frame:
[image]

I know it's a mess, but so far I'm trying to complete the code rather than get an accurate reading.

Each one hs exactly 54 lines of that. Does anyone have any ideas on what is causing the error? I'm using OpenCV 2.4.8 and Qt Creator 5.4 on Windows 7.

Comment: may you post one frame of 625.avi here, and let's see how it looks. also, i think you'd better use a group of individual images instead of an avi.

Comment: Unfortunetly it has to be a video. I'll include the frame in the OP

Comment: Maybe set a breakpoint at drawChessboardCorners, check if elements in objectPoints and corners have the same size.

Comment: Checking the size of each element is the first thing I've thought of, and yes, they are all the same size. objectPoints and imagePoints both have an equal amount of arrays in them, and each of these arrays have 54 items in them.

Comment: @YangKui I am a moron. An absolute moron. I passed corners instead of imagePoints. Got new error, though. It nulled my intrinsic matrix. And the distort coeffs are really weird (-3.80871228702875;  
  379.970212949286;  
  0.4127166512419153;  
  0.03035805582878129;  
  -4.178316666034348)

Comment: @YangKui well, I got better ones now, and these numbers seem to work oddly well. Feel free to create an answer... I can't believe that over the course of a few days, only one person noticed that corners and imagePoints are switched. Oh well. Good eye, mate.

Comment: @YangKui - I have one last question. Is there a limit to the size of objectPoints and imagePoints? If I pass them when theyir size is >25, the app hangs and stops responding, eating 50% of my CPU (currently writing code on an Acer Aspire One 722.......), while 25 or lower spews out results (odd results - focal length around "633"?) after a short while. Is there a limit or is it just my netbook being really bad?

Comment: I don't know whether there is a limitation or not, but i think size <= 25 is enough to get a good result. Focal length around 633 is not wierd. 633 is in terms of your sensor size.  I have created an answer. More details are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, corners and imagePoints have to be switched, as you have aready noticed.

In most cases (if not all), size <= 25 is enough to get a good result. Focal length around 633 is not wierd, it means the focal length is 633 * sensor size. The CCD or CMOS size must be somewhere on the INSTRUCTIONS along with your camera. Find it out , times 633, the result is your focal length.

One suggestion to reduce the number of images used: using images taken from different viewpoints.  10 images from 10 different viewpoints bring much better result than 100 images from the same ( or nearby ） viewpoints. That is one of the reasons why video is not a good input. I guess with your code, all the images passed to calibratecamera may be from nearby viewpoints. If so, the calibration accuracy degrades.

Comment: An excellent answer. I'll change my code accordingly. Unfortunetly it has to be a video... I think I'll just add a tool that'll allow the user to pick specific frames (or rather look for them around picked timestamps), and have him pick 10-15, covering the entire screen from different viewpoints, and save the results to an XML file. 633*1/2.5 converted from inches is 2532, which is nowhere near 4620 (most accurate results) or 5800 (focal length given by the manafacturer). Oh well. I'll calibrate harder.